# hpa doesn't share cpu traffic to replicas

Tags: kubernetes, cpu, hpa, statefulset

This is my hpa yaml file:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: mysql-hpa
spec:
  maxReplicas: 2
  minReplicas: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: StatefulSet 
    name: mysql
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 60
```

The problem is that while i send requests to my app with jmeter, hpa creates a 2nd pod but doesn't share the traffic to both pods, except a few times!
You can see it to the photos below..

[image]
[image]

Ιf i create a pod with 2 replicas (by yaml file) without hpa, traffic is devided normally!
Any idea?

i have another pod with 12 containers and the hpa works fine.

Comment: Is it happening only for some short time after scaling out your StatefulSet or permanently ?

Comment: No it is happening permanently! I don't know whyy

Comment: Any progress with solving this issue ? Can you provide a description how to replicate this behavior on a test kubernetes cluster ?

Comment: The problem is that it couldn't create a replica for the database... so the 2nd db was actually empty.. I'm trying to create Operators, but i didn't make it yet!!